# Execute Command on VIM Exit, And View the Output

Tags: vim, vimrc

I use `vim` for editing my PHP scripts, and I would like `vim` to automatically execute `php -l` on any `*.php` file that I exit to do a syntax check.  I've set this autocmd in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd VimLeave *.php :!php -l %
```

What I'm expecting to see is either the message:

```
No syntax errors detected in (file).
```

...or whatever parse error was encountered during the syntax check.  But nothing is displayed.

When I replace the command above with something that proves that the autocmd is actually running (like `echo % >> /tmp/vimtest`), I can see that the file gets created and appended to with the correct information.  When I replace it with something that should just output something (like `echo hello world`), I get nothing.  So I can only assume that my `php -l` command is running, but `vim` doesn't show me the output.

I know virtually nothing about vimscript and have never worked with autocmds, so I'm hoping there's a flag that I can set here that will cause the output to be displayed to the console on exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why this doesn't work as I was hoping.  The output is echo'd to the console, but when `vim` finishes exiting, it removes everything that it echo'd, so it's not visible.  This can be demonstrated with this:

```
autocmd VimLeave *.php :!echo Hello; sleep 5
```

I can see it for five seconds, then it clears and takes me back to a prompt.  I thought I could just do something like this:

```
autocmd VimLeave *.php :!php -l %; sleep 5
```

And this does work, but then it creates a five-second sleep every time I exit editing a PHP file.  I can `Ctrl-C` out of it, but that's a bad habit to get into, and adds another step to the 95% of cases where I exit a file and there are no errors.  I thought about changing `sleep 5` to `sleep 1` so that I wouldn't have to wait so long in those cases, but then it gives me only one second to view any actual errors, which might not be good.

So I wrote something a little more complex:

```
autocmd VimLeave *.php :!php -l % &> /dev/null; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ERRORS=$(( php -l % ) 2>&1 ); clear; printf "\n************************************ ERRORS ************************************\n$ERRORS\n********************************************************************************\n"; sleep 10; fi;
```

This does the following:

If there are no errors, it just exits as normal, and doesn't display any special output.  If there is an error, it gives me a nicely formatted error display like this:

```
************************************ ERRORS ************************************
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in file.php on line 4

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in ami.php on line 4
Errors parsing file.php
********************************************************************************
```

It clears the screen before displaying this error, and waits for 10 seconds.  That gives me more than enough time to view and comprehend the error.  I can always `Ctrl-C` out of the display if I'm finished before the 10 seconds is up.  If I `Ctrl-C` out, or the 10 seconds are up, it goes back to the main console that I saw before opening `vim`, just as I would normally see when exiting `vim` without any of these modifications.

This can probably be made into an autocmd function so that it's a little cleaner inside my `.vimrc` file, if I thought it was worth the time to learn how to do that.